# How display values from subform in front end?

Tags: front-end, subform, json

I created a simple component with a subform that stores data in a database. Now I need to display this data on the front page. The data is displayed as is from db

```
{"comment0":{"comment":"one"},"comment1":{"comment":"two"}}
```

How do I fix it and get values `one, two` on front-end? Please tell me step by step.

What I have:

views/myview/tmpl/default.php

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>

            <?php echo $item->comment; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

views/myview/view.html.php

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class MycomponentViewMyView extends JViewLegacy {
    protected $items;
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->items        = $this->get('Items');

        $app        = JFactory::getApplication();
        $params     = $app->getParams();
        $this->assignRef( 'params', $params );

        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            JError::raiseError(500, implode("\n", $errors));
            return false;
        }
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

also standard model

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class MyComponentModelMyModel extends JModelList {
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        if (empty($config['filter_fields']))
        {
            $config['filter_fields'] = array(
                'id', 'a.id'
            );
        }

        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
    {
        $id = JRequest::getInt('id');
        $this->setState('id', $id);
    }

    protected function getListQuery()
    {
        $db     = $this->getDbo();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select(
            $this->getState(
                'list.select',
                'a.id, a.comment,'
            )
        );
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__mycomponent').' AS a');
        $query->where('(a.state IN (0, 1))');

        if ($id = $this->getState('id'))
        {
            $query->where('a.id = '.(int) $id);
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `echo $item->comment;` is only looping one time and is displaying `{"comment0":{"comment":"one"},"comment1":{"comment":"two"}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a Joomla-specific fix for this, but it seems that you will simply need to decode your json string.  I don't know how your actual data may vary or if you will want to including any conditional handling, but you can just loop through the generated multi-dimensional data.

Assuming `echo $item->comment;` inside of your loop is displaying `{"comment0":{"comment":"one"},"comment1":{"comment":"two"}}`, then you can

Here is a [demonstration](https://3v4l.org/XfV81):

```
$comment_json = '{"comment0":{"comment":"one"},"comment1":{"comment":"two"}}';
↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
------------------------------------- this is effectively your $item->comment
                        ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
$comments = json_decode($comment_json);

foreach ($comments as $key => $set) {
    echo "$key contains:\n";
    foreach ($set as $label => $value) {
        echo "\t$label : $value\n";
    }
    echo "---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
comment0 contains:
    comment : one
---
comment1 contains:
    comment : two
---
```

*I've added `\n` and `\t` for better readability.

There will be different ways to handle the decoded data, but this is probably the easiest to read and manage.

Generally speaking, storing data in a database as a json string *can* indicate a suboptimal database design in some cases ...but I'll avoid that debate because too much is unknown about your data and its intended usage.

Answer (score 0):

It works. thanks for the solution mickmackusa.

example

views/myview/tmpl/default.php

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item) : ?>
<?php
```

```
$comment_json = $item->comment;
$comments = json_decode($comment_json);
foreach ($comments as $key => $set) {
    echo "$key contains:\n";
    foreach ($set as $label => $value) {
        echo nl2br ("\t$label : $value\n");
    }
    echo "---\n";
}
?>
```

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am happy to hear that my solution was useful to you.  However, I don't  feel that there is any benefit to adding your redundant answer to this page.

Comment: I've published my answer for beginners, it fully explains exactly where to place the code. My experience shows that the lack of a complete instruction can create additional questions and take a lot of time.

Comment: I would have been happy to edit my answer if you felt it wasn't clear enough.  I went out of my way to explain what the variable represents via coded comment.